# Do you need to stop window navigation when doing an ajax call whose return doesn't matter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If I want to run an ajax call with jQuery on a link (`<a href="/wherever">`) click, do I need `e.preventDefault()` inside the jQuery click listener? I normally would, but this is more of a tracking ajax call and so the result from it won't matter, and I want the window to navigate to the clicked link's page.

Assuming the fastest internet available, would the page navigation ever cause the ajax call to fail?

Comment: Yes, it can fail. But you can always redirect user on success handler

Comment: No, it would not cause the ajax call to fail; however, if it does fail for whatever reason, you'd never know.

Comment: I now have two conflicting answers :( I ended up having to change it to include `e.preventDefault()` anyway because the functionality from the client changed.